# Crop image in java with thumbnailator

Tags: java, thumbnails, crop

I have picture which i want to crop, but i want to cut off onlu 100 px from the left of the picture.

I'm using thumbnailator.

Do you know maybe, how to do it?

Tanks

Answer (score 4):

It's easy. Just do this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Thumbnails.of(inputStream).crop(Positions.CENTER_LEFT).size(100,100).keepAspectRatio(true).toOutputStream(outputStream);
byte picture[] = outputStream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: `crop()` method does NOT actually crop image as it is expected, it creates thumbnail with some fancy logic.

To crop without rescaling `.sourceRegion(x, y, w, h)` + `scale(1)` can be used.